# Generate Bootstrap 4 custom css

Tags: sass, bootstrap-4

I am trying to create a Bootstrap 4 custom css file. We already have one for Bootstrap 3. As I understand I need to take vars from config.json and enter them into _custom.scss and then compile it. Here is a fragment of config.json:

```
"vars": {
"@gray-base": "#000",
"@gray-darker": "lighten(@gray-base, 13.5%)",
"@gray-dark": "lighten(@gray-base, 20%)",
"@gray": "lighten(@gray-base, 33.5%)",
"@gray-light": "lighten(@gray-base, 46.7%)",
"@gray-lighter": "lighten(@gray-base, 93.5%)",
```

As you can see all these vars are based on @gray-base. But if I look into _variables.scss file I won't even find that variable. The B3 file was created by another developer so I am kind of lost at this point. Any help?

Thanks

Update 1.
The vars should be taken from _variables.scss file.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you still need an answer for this question. I will answer anyway.

Bootstrap 4 is having a completely different approach than Bootstrap 3. You can't simply replace Bootstrap 3 variables to Bootstrap 4 file structure. You have to migrate BS3 website to BS4.